# How would one go about finding the inverse of a matrix containg only variables?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Lets say I have the following matrix :
$$
   \left[\begin{array}{cc}
   z & y & x & w   \\
   s-a & t-b & u-c & v-d   \\
   a & b & c & d   \\
   3s & 3t & 3u & 3v   \\
   \end{array} \right]
$$
How would I go about demonstrating whether or not this matrix can be inverted?
I've been ready about the (many) criteria for inverting a matrix and yet I just can't figure this out. All I know is that it's det=-30 from a previous question.

Comment: Any square matrix whose determinant is nonzero can be inverted.
But the determinant is not $-30$.  Note the relation between the last three rows.

Comment: The determinant is 0, so you can't the matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may know how operations on the rows (or columns) of a matrix affect its determinant:

- Adding a multiple of a row/column to another row/column leaves the determinant unchanged
- Multiplying a row/column with a constant multiplies the determinant with the same constant
- Swapping two rows/columns multiplies the determinant by $-1$.

Now, in your matrix, do the following:

- Add the third row to the second.
- Add the fourth row multiplied by $-1/3$ to the second.

Verify that you will obtain a matrix in which the second row will be all-zeros. Thus its determinant is zero. Thus, the determinant of the original matrix is also zero.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding the determinant as with numbers, you will obtain a polynomial. The matrix will be invertible for all values of the variables, except where the polynomial vanishes (roots).

But in your particular case, the polynomial is... particular.